# RegExp for remove whitespaces before parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to remove all whitespaces between something (let's say a function name) and its parenthesis:

this is what I have

```
function_name       (params);
```

and this is what i'd like to obtain

```
function_name(params);
```

is there any regExp that can help me using javascript function replace?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
'function_name       (params);'.replace(/(\w+)\s+\(/, '$1(')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace multiple whitespace characters in front of a literal parenthesis using a global search.

```
var str="function_name       (params);";
var n=str.replace(/\s+\(/g,"(");
```

Comment: thank you Absolute. I just want the whitespaces before the parenthesis to be erased so the answer that Arun gave me is just fine. Anyway thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: @Jannuzzo You'll want to mark his as the answer then. Otherwise other people may still answer.

Comment: I know.. but i can't do it right now. I must wait another 3 minutes. :S

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

```
var input="function_name      (/* arguments if any */)";

result=input.replace(/(\w+)\s+\(/,"$1(");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="function_name         (params);";
result=str.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

**or**
   `result=str.replace(/\s/g,'');`